# Find index based on the minimum number for every group

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to extract the index based of the minimum number for every Group

```
Group <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")

Number <- c(12,45,15,65,54,21,23,12,3,5,6,11,34,656,754)

data.frame(Group,Number)


   Group Number
1      A     12
2      A     45
3      A     15
4      A     65
5      A     54
6      B     21
7      B     23
8      C     12
9      C      3
10     C      5
11     C      6
```

The result should be a vector that contain the indices:

Answer

```
vector <- (1,6,9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a sequence column, grouped by 'Group', `summarise` by returning the corresponding row number based on the index of `min` value of 'Number' (`which.min`) and `pull` the column as a `vector`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    group_by(Group) %>% 
    summarise(n = rn[which.min(Number)]) %>%
    pull(n)
#[1] 1 6 9
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C", "C", "C"), Number = c(12L, 45L, 15L, 65L, 54L, 21L, 23L, 
12L, 3L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(row_n = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  slice_min(Number)
# A tibble: 3 x 3
# Groups:   Group [3]
  Group Number row_n
  <chr>  <dbl> <int>
1 A         12     1
2 B         12     7
3 C          3     8
```

The row numbers are in column `row_n`. If you want outputted only the row numbers, add `%>% ungroup() %>% select(-c(1:2))` like so:

```
df %>%
  mutate(row_n = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  slice_min(Number) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-c(1:2))
# A tibble: 3 x 1
  row_n
  <int>
1     1
2     7
3     8
```

Data:

```
Group <- c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C","C")
Number <- c(12,45,65,54,21,23,12,3,5,6,34)
df <- data.frame(Group,Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

This function returns the index `i` of the smallest value in `v`

```
FUN = function(v, i) i[which.min(v)]
```

Here are the values by group

```
v = split(df$Number, df$Group)
```

and the index into the original data.frame by group

```
i = split(seq_along(df$Number), df$Group)
```

Apply our function to each group

```
mapply(FUN, v, i)
```

In one go:

```
FUN = function(v, i) i[which.min(v)]
v = split(df$Number, df$Group)
i = split(seq_along(df$Number), df$Group)
mapply(FUN, v, i)
```